# How do I change a python package version in just a specific environment?

Tags: python

I initially have pandas==1.5 both in my base environment, and in a specific environment

[image]

For a project's purpose, I had to downgrade my pandas version in my project environment to version 1.4. However, when I downgraded the pandas version in that environment, the version in my base environment got downgraded as well.

[image]

Why is this so, and how can I keep my package version downgrade to just a specific environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to installing your packages through `Conda` rather than pip since you're activating your environment through `Conda` itself.

```
conda install pandas=1.4.4
```

Remove the existing package and keep the latest one as you had earlier in both base and inside your environment. Then try to downgrade through conda.

You could read up more [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment), on using pip inside conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

pip install 'package-name'==2.1.0

You can use above command